# Variable scope in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and I have noticed something that I can't quite understand.

Given two scripts:

```
#Script 1
$test = "This is a test"
& ".\script2.ps1"
```

```
#Script 2
Write-Host $test
```

When I run script1 "This is a test" is printed.

My question is: why can script2 see the variable defined in script1 when the variable isn't defined as global?

The only reason I can think of is that script2 isn't called but just imported by '&' but I'm not sure this is corret.

Comment: Please read [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Comment: PowerShell uses _dynamic_ scoping (instead of _lexical_ scoping, as most other languages like C# do). A child scope _copies_ the variables of the parent scope, so it can read their values but can't modify them directly (for reference type variables, it can modify properties though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `&` is the [**Call operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-).

***The call operator executes in a child scope*** and the **calling scope is the parent scope**. Quoting from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#parent-and-child-scopes),

> The functions or scripts you call may call other functions, creating a
> hierarchy of child scopes whose root scope is the global scope.
> Unless you explicitly make the items private, **the items in the
> parent scope are available to the child scope**.